# How to invest 10000 a week for 36 weeks

Tags: investing, short-term

How would you invest $10,000 USD in the USA a week for 36 weeks. After that point the entire amount has to be returned. Meaning $360,000 I'm assuming treasury bonds but could you do a short term treasury bond?

Comment: Country? Risk-profile acceptable (does "entire amount has to be returned" just mean you want to liquidate your position in 36 weeks' time, even if there are losses, or that there must not be any losses?)

Comment: @Hilmar - I would assume that $10,000 USD  is kind of self explanatory

Comment: If you want a guaranteed return of  principal after 36 weeks plus  some gain then you're limited to MM, CD's, and any other fixed income of short duration (35 weeks).

Comment: @BobBaerker Just for info re. your first comment: at the time of Hilmar's comment, the question just had **10000** with no indication of currency or country.

Comment: Depends on what recourse is behind the repayment of the principal.

Comment: Better to buy and sell / flip a property with the same money in the same time...

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can buy treasury bills in $100 increments with terms of 4, 13, 26, and 52 weeks. You could also reinvest bills that are kept to maturity so that you get as much interest as possible.  For example, you could buy a 26-week (6-month) bill with the first 10,000, then reinvest it with another 4-week bill at week 27, then reinvest that at week 31.

Note that *technically* you buy t-bills at a discount, so you might not be able to invest all $10,000 each week. Since you might spend, say, $9,910 for $10,000 in bills, you won't be able to invest every penny, but it shouldn't make a huge difference.

I also wouldn't expect much in terms of return for this. Since your average investment horizon is 18 weeks (.346 years), and the current t-bill rates for 13 and 26 week bills are 1.85% and 2.05%, you can expect an annualized  return of about 1.95%, or about 0.6% for your investment, which would be about $2k.